# Xcode 6 sprite kit - SourceKitService terminated

Tags: ios, swift, sourcekit

I got SourceKitService terminated when I implement this method:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!)
```

if I remove the  **!** , it works.
But then I got an error in my code of course.
Full code:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

    for touch: AnyObject in touches {

        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if nodeAtPoint(location).name == "plane" {
            println("plane touched")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in beta software.

Comment: So we can't implement the func touchesBegan in xcode 6 ?

Comment: @user3722523 you can, but just without syntax highlighting until the bug is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Running on beta4, and I was able to declare the method without issue. `for touch: AnyObject in touches {` looks to be the issue, since when I replace `AnyObject` with `UITouch`, which is more specific to what you want to get, I get the compiler error: `NSSet! cannot be implicitly downcast to UITouch`, which means that syntax tries to cast the array to the type. It would seem casting the item isn't possible yet. See [Annotation error in Swift for loop with array and UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24091370). Here's the same body code without compiler errors:

```
for item in touches {

    let location = (item as UITouch).locationInNode(self)    

    if self.nodeAtPoint(location).name == "plane" {
        println("plane touched")
    }

}
```

The errors weren't enough to trigger the SourceKit crash for me. Maybe you have other problem areas in the code?

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me also. I solved it for now, by first converting the NSSet to an NSArray and then use the for..in way of looping. This didn't crash:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet!, withEvent event: UIEvent!) {

        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)

        let touchArray: NSArray = touches.allObjects

        for element in touchArray {
            println("\(element)")
        }

    }
```